# Python storm/web.py: Correctly handling DisconnectionError with MySQL database

Tags: python, web.py, apache-storm

I am writing a web service based on web.py, using storm as an ORM layer for querying records from a MySQL database. The web service is deployed via mod_wsgi using Apache2 on a Linux box. I create a connection to the MySQL database server when the script is started using storm's `create_database()` method. This is also the point where I create a `Store` object, which is used later on to perform queries when a request comes in.

After some hours of inactivity, `store.find()` throws a `DisconnectionError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`. I am not surprised that the database connection is dropped as Apache/mod_wsgi reuses the Python processes without reinitializing them for a long time. My question is how to correctly deal with this?

I have tried setting up a mechanism to keep alive the connection to the MySQL server by sending it a recurring "SELECT 1" (every 300 seconds). Unfortunately that fixed the problem on our testing machine, but not on our demo deployments (ouch) while both share the same MySQL configuration (`wait_timeout` is set to 8 hours).

I have searched for solutions for reconnecting the storm store to the database, but didn't find anything sophisticated. The only recommendation seems to be that one has to catch the exception, treat it like an inconsistency, call `rollback()` on the store and then retry. However, this would imply that I either have to wrap the whole `Store` class or implement the same retry-mechanism over and over. Is there a better solution or am I getting something completely wrong here?

**Update:** I have added a web.py processor that gracefully handles the disconnection error by recreating the storm Store if the exception is caught and then retrying the operation like recommended by Andrey. However, this is an incomplete and suboptimal solution as (a) the store is referenced by a handful of objects for re-use, which requires an additional mechanism to re-wire the store reference on each of these objects, and (b), it doesn't cover transaction handling (rollbacks) when performing writes on the database. However, at least it's an acceptable fix for all read operations on the store for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use web.py's [application processor](http://webpy.org/cookbook/application_processors) to wrap your controller methods and catch DisconnectionError from them. Something like this:

```
def my_processor(handler): 
    tries = 3
    while True:
        try:
            return handler() 
        except DisconnectionError:
            tries -= 1
            if tries == 0:
                raise
```

Or you may check cookbook entry of how application processor is used to have SqlAlchemy with web.py: http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy and make something similar for storm:

```
def load_storm(handler):
    web.ctx.store = Store(database)
    try:
        return handler()
    except web.HTTPError:
       web.ctx.store.commit()
       raise
    except:
        web.ctx.store.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        web.ctx.store.commit()

app.add_processor(load_storm)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I am already doing something similar. However, this unfortunately doesn't answer the actual question -- What is the correct way to handle the error w.r.t storm and how transactions are handled internally, especially when using storm with web.py?

Comment: I haven't used storm, but from the docs it has `commit` and `rollback` methods, just like SqlAlchemy. Also docs mention that storm's `store` is [not thread safe](https://storm.canonical.com/Manual#Working_with_multiple_threads), this means you should create it every request, or implement your own store manager. I've updated my example with how I think it should work, but don't take it for granted.